# Anybody cross compiled Mono for MIPS 64 using uClibc?

Tags: mono, mips, embedded-linux, uclibc

I am trying to statically cross compile Mono for MIPS.  I am able to compile Mono, but it is always dynamically linked with it's dependencies, even though I specify static to the compiler.

I wrote a test program and I am able to statically compile it with my toolchain and run it on the target platform.  I am not sure if I am missing something or if it isn't possible.  I built my toolchain using [buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/).

**EDIT**

To make things a little more clear, I would like to statically compile mono with it's dependencies.  The dependencies that mono rely's on are:  GLib, pkg-config, and gettext.  I believe GLib is a direct dependency and GLib depends on pkg-config and gettext.

I can post my environment variables and configure command if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's been a while since I tried this, but I wanted to report what I learned.  For one, I found out that the MIPS processor is 64-bit and not 32-bit like I was initially told for the embedded device that I was targeting.  Second, when I was working on this, Mono didn't have MIPS 64-bit support yet.  After a little research, I saw that a group at [N-iX](http://www.n-ix.com) was porting Mono to support the MIPS 64-bit architecture based off the 32-bit port that was already done.  The 64-bit port was being done for a company called [SiCortex, Inc.](http://sicortex.com) and N-iX was trying to get their patches applied to the main Mono development trunk.  You can check this [forum thread](http://www.nabble.com/-PATCH--Mono-port-to-the-MIPS-64-bit-to23175539ef1367.html#a23175539) out for more information.  I posted stating I wanted to help with testing, but I never got a response.

As far as statically compiling Mono, I learned that Mono uses [libtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/) for linking it's libraries together.  I will need to learn more about this tool, before trying to statically compile.  I stopped after learning that Mono didn't support MIPS 64-bit yet.  I will also need to see if the 64-bit port patches ever got applied to Mono.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a fully statically linked Mono you will have to build all it's dependencies (and their dependencies recursively) as static libraries first. Only then you can build a truly static Mono.

Comment: I was afraid this might be the answer.  In buildroot, I chose the packages that mono depended on to be built with the toolchain, so they'd be in the lib and bin folders of the toolchain for linking.  I just didn't want to have to go through the process without somebody else thinking the same.  I will give it a try and report back the steps.

Answer (score 0):

On one of the stackoverflow podcasts recently, Miguel said they ported Mono to iPhone, using a lot of static I think. While not 64-bit, it shows nasty things can be done to Mono.

Comment: What they did was statically compile a .NET application, which comes with a lot of draw backs.  Close to what I am looking for, but not quite.  I am looking to statically compile the Mono runtime.  This would negate the need to statically compile a .NET application, because the runtime will be available.